# How to pull version of docker file from hub?

Tags: docker

Why doesn't the following pull centos version 6?

```
docker pull centos:v6
```

> Tag v6 not found in repository docker.io/library/centos

or this:

```
docker pull centos6
```

> Error: image library/centos6:latest not found

Answer (score 1):

How about this? From here https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

```
docker pull centos:centos6
```

Or

```
docker pull centos:6
```

The format is

```
<container_name>:tag
```

Without a tag, it'll pull `latest`. All the `code_blocks` on Docker Hub represent tags.